# Make sprites unmovable

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I have created a SpriteKit game for shape recognition where there are two same shapes one is at lower part of the scene while other one which is to be matched is at upper side of the scene. I am creating these shapes by calling method from other class which contain code to create the shape.

I am able to do all the things in the proper way and works fine. But I am unable to find that how to make upper side shapes static. Mean user must be able to drag only lower side shapes to upper side shapes for matching but the should not be able to drag upper side shapes to match with lower side shapes. I have so far searched in SpriteKit Programming Guide by Apple but there is no such clue in that that helps me perform the above mentioned task.

Please help me if anyone can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to do is set their name when you create them. Use a constant is any easy way so you ensure you are adding / checking the right name.

```
static NSString * const kCanMoveMe = @"movable";
static NSString * const kCanNotMoveMe = @"not-movable";

// for example
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];
sprite.name = kCanMoveMe

SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];
sprite.name = kCanNotMoveMe
```

Then when you touch check the name and then you know if you can move it or not.

Comment: Although this will work, subclassing SKSpriteNode and adding a `isMoveable` BOOL property is likely a better route. Using the `name` property is kind of hacky as now the property's name no longer reflects it's true functionality.

Comment: @prototypical I agree, but Programmer wanted a simple solution. Using user data rather than name is another better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage the SKNode .userData property to store custom node data for the actual sprite, in your situation if it is movable or not or any other game specific data.

More info here: [Apple documentation about the userData property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest subclassing the SKSpriteNode and adding a `isMoveable` BOOL property to designate if it is able to be moved.

The other answers will definitely work, but both lack advantages of your property being named appropriately and accessible via the Xcode code completion capabilities.

For example in Xcode you would type `mySprite.i` and the `isMoveable` BOOL property would be available to choose for code completion.